# como chequear variables en php

Tags: php, variables

tengo una variable en php llamada $marca y yo quisiera saber si el valor $marca es "Coca Cola", si es a si quiero que haga un echo de "la marca es coca cola" si el valor de marca no es coca cola quiero que diga "no conocemos el nombre de la marca". ¿como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Mediante condicionales (*`if/else`*), por otro lado para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta por favor lee [ask] y trata de aportar un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($marca == "coca cola"){
   echo "La marca es: $marca";
}else{
   echo "No conocemos la $marca";
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], al margen de que la pregunta tiene problemas de formato y es seguro quede cerrada tratemos de que la respuesta tenga un mayor contenido, por ejemplo explicando como esto soluciona el problema